# Run a script over multiple files in unix

Tags: unix, shell

Started to learn some shell scripting. I have a perl script that runs on one file.  How would I write a shell script to run the perl script a bunch of times on all files with keyword "filename" in it?

So in English,

```
for /filename/ in filenames  
    perl myscript.pl completefilename
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
find . -name "filename*" -exec perl myscript.pl '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -path "\*filename\*" -exec perl myscript.pl {} \;
```

edit: escaped stars, didn't want the markup here

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in $(\ls -d filenames)
do
    perl myscript.pl $i
done
```

The backslash in front of the 'ls' command is to temporarily disable any aliases.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

And if you have spaces in your filenames, use the old standby

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 perl myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
files=`ls -1 *`
for $file in $files;
do
    perl myscript.pl $file;
done
```

Comment: This only works as long as there are no filenames with spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

`$ for file in filename1 filename2 filename3; do perl myscript $file; done`

Instead of the space separated list of filenames you can also use wildcards, for instance:

`$ for file in *.txt *.csv; do perl myscript $file; done`

Answer (score 0):

FILES="*keyword*"

for f in "$FILES"
do
  perl myscript.pl $f
done

From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Comment: But $f pulls up the keyword, whereas I would like the entire filename (that includes the keyword).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the zsh shell, which gives you a very nice way to run a command recursively on a set of subdirectories.  It also allows you to change the suffix of the file, which is handly when using lame to create MP3 files of .wav files:

for i in **/*.wav; lame $i $i:r.mp3

You can also pipe the output of one command to another, which I something I use frequently when I'm downloading a number of bittorrent files and want to see the percentage that each download has completed:

for i in **/*.txt; grep -H percent $i | tail -1